# Song playing in Lift Me Up first dance scene

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

So guys, help me out. I am getting really frustrated because I can't find this song anywhere.

In the movie *Lift Me Up*, when her stepdad goes out jogging, she turns on music and starts dancing. I have been trying to find that song, but with no succes.
Using Shazam gave nothing.
I googled all the lyrics, but no matches showed up.
I tried the songs in the credits, none of them fit.
So, help me, what is this song called?

The lyrics:

> nail me to your self-righteous cross forgive me for what i've done and what i am your wicked confidence is holes and lies i may be a young woman but some of us have eyes
>   (La la la and more la)
>   Im crying out of frustration you are such a lost cause and its such a waste 
>   How can you forgive a wrong that wasnt done?
>   You have to be the only one who never was now im sifting through the insignificance and im dying just to find redemption
>   (La la la, more la and song stops)

Also, the credits talk about a singer called Lexie Hofer, but there is practically nothing online about her, and maybe two songs that aren't the one I am looking for. The other songs in the credits can't be found. (Lost cause, letting go, the escape, sinking)

Comment: @Noralie Can you provide a link to that scene? If might be helpful.

Comment: I watched it on netflix, so I dont actually have a link

Comment: Can you provide the exact moment when the song starts?

Comment: Its in the beginning of the movie, first few minutes. The opening scene sort of. Were the stepdad leaves for a jog and the girl turns on the music to dance, that is the song.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Lost Cause*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Xee2nOxbYo) by Lexie Hofer is the song you are looking for.

Comment: Okay, so this is super frustrating. While looking for the song, I came by this site a few times, but could never find the actual song. Now I am opening the site on my laptop (instead of my phone) and suddenly there is a list of featured songs. Wtf. So, as it appears, it just cant be found on my phone. No list of songs at all. I feel really frustrated about the design of the website now xD But thanks for making me check again on my laptop, at least I have it now xD

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the third song in the link below, you will find the song that are you (and me) looking for:

[Lift Me Up Soundtrack](https://www.cdbaby.com/cd/liftmeupmotionpicturesou)